# Bash output of date in bash script

Tags: bash, date

I wrote this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
target="1.1.1.1"
while true;
do
        ping $target -c 1 -v > /dev/null
        if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
                echo "$(date +"%d/%m/%y %R:%S")" >> netStabilityLog
        fi
        sleep 5s
done
```

It works almost perfectly, there is just one problem. In the ouptut file `netStabilityLog`, I get:

```
28/06/22 17:19:26
28/06/22 17:20:06
28/06/22 17:45
28/06/22 18:36:00
28/06/22 18:51
```

Sometimes, the seconds are not shown. Why is that?

Comment: Side note: why `echo "$(date …)"`? What's wrong with sole `date …`?

Comment: Do you have two copies of your script running, one that you show us and one that is possibly an older version of the same script without the `:%S` bit in the date format?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Even if, why would seconds show up from time to time if i am running the same command every 5 seconds or so?

Comment: @JulianZalewski You only output the timestamp when the `ping` fails. If you have multiple copies of the script running in the background, it could fail for one copy (then do output), succeed for the next `ping` in the other script (no output), and so on, depending on the quality of the network.

Comment: change the script to save a file with a different name, and see what happens then. If you have an old copy of the script running, it'd still write to the old filename. Alternatively, change the output in some way that would be _obviously_ different. The man pages say `%R` is the same as `%H:%M`, and you have the other colon hard-coded there, so I can't see how the seconds could disappear. You could use `%T` for `%H:%M:%S` too, and the date would be better presented as `%Y-%m-%d`.

Comment: I changed the script, made sure only one instance is running. Everything seems to work well right now, so that must have been it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you may have had multiple, slightly different, copies of the script running at once, each writing to the same output file. At least one running version of the script was not adding the seconds to its output.

As for the script itself, I could possibly give my take on it, which gets rid of the external `date` utility and which does the conditional outputting and redirection differently.  It also sorts out the missing quoting.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ipaddr=1.1.1.1

while true; do
    if ! ping -c 1 "$ipaddr" >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
        printf '%(%d/%m/%y %T)T\n' -1
    fi
    sleep 5
done >>netStabilityLog
```

This uses the `%(...)T` formatting string with `printf`, introduced in `bash` release 4.2.  The argument `-1` causes `printf` to use the current time when creating the output timestamp.  It also does not redirect for each `printf` call but rather once only, for the outer loop.

The code gets rid of the explicit test against `$?` by using `ping` directly with `if`. The `ping` is not called with `-v` (for verbose output) as we're discarding the output anyway.

Comment: I'd also recommend `%F` (short for `%Y-%m-%d`) instead of `%d/%m/%y` as less ambiguous and better for sorting.

Comment: If you press Ctrl-C whilst sleep is running, that exits the script whether `sleep` is the loop condition or not. But see [Unable to stop a bash script with Ctrl+C](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/230421) about the problem with bash + ping specifically.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for that link.